# GUI Different When Compiled

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am working on my first C# Application and am using Visual Studio 2012, I am having an issue regarding the GUI, when I compile my application it is different from the way it looks in the editor.

[image: Screenshot showing the difference between the editor and run-time view of my form]

Comment: What exactly looks different? The fact that the compiled application is using the visual styles? The size? Check your sizing. Heck, start by telling us whether this is a WinForm of WPF based UI.

Comment: How about you give us your codes? Or embed the screen shot of the application here.

Comment: I am not talking about the Aero theme but the fact the last text field is larger than it's supposed to be and that the window is longer than it's supposed to be.

Comment: @TomTom I would like to add that I have done nothing special to the GUI through code apart from adding a new line character to the Label on the top right.

Comment: Points to simply not properly laid out form to me.

Comment: Did you set any of the automatic sizing properties for the text field? Also, what does the form's `AutoScaleMode` property say? Please try setting it from `Font` to `DPI`. Did you add any code that might change the dimensions?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I don't see any `AutoScaleMode` property for the text field.

Comment: That's why I said "the **form's** `AutoScaleMode` property" :-)

Comment: Everything you need to do in code to manage to get the control sizes correct is not a solution. Usually, forms look about the same when running as when designed. Changes in size as you are experiencing should not occur, unless you have some code that does resize stuff when running. If you need to keep stretch controls, please use the respective Dock property. To make sure you're not doing anything wrong, please create a brand new application project, design the form and run it without adding any code. It should look the same as in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Windows Forms designer always uses the 'Windows Basic' theme, however in your case Windows itself is using the 'Aero' theme, leading to the form and layout being slightly different visually when run. It shouldn't be a problem in terms of functionality. You don't know what crazy theme your end users might be running.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the 'SizeToContent' property of your Dialog/Window to 'Height'

Edit:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    SizeToContent="Height">
```

If your project is in winforms then I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: I tried to look that up but as I am new to C# I don't quite understand the documentation I found, care to explain?

Comment: Actuall that is not a good solution, as the size of the form should by default be the same in designer and at runtime.

Comment: Oops. Didn't see the tag. Monday mornings aren't my kind of mornings.